# System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#

I am getting this exception...

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: typeName
   at HomeInventory2.Services.Factory.GetService(String servicename) in C:\Users\Protego\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HomeInventory2\HomeInventory2\Services\Factory.cs:line 37
   at HomeInventory2.Business.Manager.GetService(String name) in C:\Users\Protego\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HomeInventory2\HomeInventory2\Business\Manager.cs:line 14
   at HomeInventory2.Business.InventoryMngr.Create(CreateInventory inv) in C:\Users\Protego\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HomeInventory2\HomeInventory2\Business\InventoryMngr.cs:line 19
   at HomeInventory2.Form1.submitButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Protego\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HomeInventory2\HomeInventory2\Form1.cs:line 52
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Stemming from this code -

```
private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateInventory create = new CreateInventory();
            create.ItemAmount = textBoxAmount.Text;
            create.ItemCategory = textBoxCategories.Text;
            create.ItemProperties = textBoxValue.Text;
            create.ItemValue = textBoxValue.Text;

            InventoryMngr invtryMngr = new InventoryMngr();
            invtryMngr.Create(create);

        }
```

That code should end in a file being created with those values being saved to a text file.  Obviously something is breaking down along the line - I am assuming in the InventoryMngr file which looks like this.

```
namespace HomeInventory2.Business
{
    public class InventoryMngr : Manager
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// persists the inventory information
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inv"></param>
        public void Create(CreateInventory inv)
        {
            InventorySvc inventorySvc =
            (InventorySvc)GetService(typeof(InventorySvc).Name);
            inventorySvc.CreateInventory(inv);
        }
    }
}
```

The business manager get service

```
namespace HomeInventory2.Business
{
    public abstract class Manager
    {
        private Factory factory = Factory.GetInstance();
        protected IService GetService(String name)
        {
            return factory.GetService(name);
        }
    }
}
```

And the Factory getservice

```
public IService GetService(string servicename)
{
    Type type;
    Object obj = null;
    try
    {
        type = Type.GetType(GetImplName(servicename));
        obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception occured: {0}", e);
        throw e;
    }
    return (IService)obj;
}
```

GetImplName

```
private string GetImplName(string servicename)
        {
            NameValueCollection settings =
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
            return settings.Get(servicename);
        }
```

Comment: Where is the `throw new ArgumentNullException("typeName");` line located?

Comment: You don't have to assume, use the debug tools at your disposal

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it, what is the question about? If that's 'where is the error?' than it's in `Factory.cs:line 37`, stack trace states this pretty much clear. Plz clarify you question.

Comment: Please add the code from both `HomeInventory2.Business.Manager.GetService` and `HomeInventory2.Services.Factory.GetService`.  You are calling `Manager.GetService` correctly, so it is something further down the line.  `Manager.GetService` might not be passing the string name correctly.

Comment: best thing to do is try debug the code and see which variable is Null. Won't take too long to step through this code.

Comment: Okay, now can you post the code for `GetImplName`.  Seems like something may be wrong in it and it's returning null, which `Type.GetType` doesn't like.

Comment: Okay, check my answer out.  You're missing your appSettings stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
NameValueCollection settings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
return settings.Get(servicename);
```

Make sure your app.config/web.config has the correct `AppSettings` values.  `settings.Get(servicename)` isn't finding a key for `servicename`.

So if the servicename is "AwesomeService", you need an element in appSettings like:

`<add key="AwesomeService" value="somevalue"/>`

Answer (score -1):

I modify your code like bellow:

```
public void Create(CreateInventory inv)
{
    InventorySvc inventorySvc =
        (InventorySvc)GetService((typeof(InventorySvc)).toString());
    inventorySvc.CreateInventory(inv);
}
```

Comment: that just gives me an error saying that System.Type does not contain a definition for toString...

Comment: This won't change anything, as the string name is already getting passed to `GetService`.  `typeof(InventorySvc).Name` correctly returns the string name of `InventorySvc`.